# How do I put a div between parent div and its child?

Tags: css, html, z-index, parent

How do I put the `#stranger` div in between the `#mother` and `#child`?  Right now, the `#stranger` div covers both the `#mother` and `#child`!

```
<head> 
  <style>
  #mother{
    position:absolute;
    display:block;
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    background-color:green;
    padding:40px;
    z-index:1000;
  }
  #child{
    position:relative;
    display:block;
    width:180px;
    height:180px;
    background-color:yellow;
    z-index:6000;
  }
  #stranger{
    position:relative;
    display:block;
    width:300px;
    height:600px;
    background-color:black;
    z-index:1500;
  }
  </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Z-index Test</h1>
    <h1>How Do I put #stranger between #mother and #child?</h1>
    <div id='mother'>
        <div id='child'></div>
    </div>
    <div id='stranger'></div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: I would upvote if I had no ethical conscience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because #child is nested inside of #mother. If #mother is lower than #stranger, #mother's #child is lower than stranger, too. See this explanation of [stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Understanding_z-index/The_stacking_context).

You would get the result I think you expect if your markup was like so:

```
<body>
    <div id='mother'></div>
    <div id='child'></div>
    <div id='stranger'></div>
</body>
```

Then they would all be in the same stacking context.

Comment: thx, but I thought I made it between b4 even they r parent and child,now I can't, weird.So if I put stranger into mother div and become her child will works too.